# elasticsearch search hits empty when results are found

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem with a nested query in elasticsearch. I'm building a complex nested query via the java api to run a filtered query over my index. The results get back from elasticsearch indicate that there is 1 match ([total:1, took:79ms]), but this is not returning any "hits" as part of the response.

```
def response = client.search(request).actionGet()
def searchHits = response.hits() // <--- this is empty

result.total = searchHits.totalHits() // <--- this is populated with one
result.took = response.getTook()
```

Running the exact same query via curl or a rest client correctly brings back the entire matching document.  As such I know the query is constructed correctly in both circumstances.

The size and from parameters are both set to the defaults, which should be returning documents.

If I move the nested query into the filter section the, I get the same matching document, but the hits() object is populated.

The query itself is below

```
{
  "filtered" : {
    "query" : {
      "bool" : {
    "must" : [ {
      "nested" : {
        "query" : {
          "bool" : {
            "must_not" : {
              "bool" : {
                "must" : [ {
                  "range" : {
                    "nested.from" : {
                      "from" : "2013-06-01T23:00:14.343Z",
                      "to" : "2013-06-02T23:00:14.343Z",
                      "include_lower" : true,
                      "include_upper" : true
                    }
                  }
                }, {
                  "term" : {
                    "nested.status" : "accepted"
                  }
                } ]
              }
            },
            "should" : [ {
              "bool" : {
                "must" : [ {
                  "range" : {
                    "nested.from" : {
                      "from" : "2013-06-01T23:00:14.343Z",
                      "to" : "2013-06-02T23:00:14.343Z",
                      "include_lower" : true,
                      "include_upper" : true
                    }
                  }
                }, {
                  "term" : {
                    "nested.status" : "saved"
                  }
                } ]
              }
            } ]
          }
        },
        "path" : "nested"
      }
    } ]
      }
    } ]
  }
},
"filter" : {
  "and" : {
    "filters" : [ {
      "type" : {
        "value" : "user"
      }
    }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed - upgraded to a new version of elasticsearch.

Seems like version 0.20.x and below don't like nested queries built using the java api.